# Porting OpenGLES code from iOS to Mac

Tags: ios, macos, opengl, opengl-es

I'm porting a couple of hundred lines of iOS code to Mac that use `OpenGLES`, in particular, `EAGLContext` and `CAEAGLLayer`.

So far I changed the `OpenGLES.framework` to the `OpenGL.framework` and added:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
#import <OpenGLES/EAGL.h>
#import <OpenGLES/EAGLDrawable.h>
#import <OpenGLES/ES1/gl.h>
#import <OpenGLES/ES1/glext.h>
#else
#import <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#endif

#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
#define MYOpenGLContext EAGLContext
#define MYOpenGLLayer CAEAGLLayer
#else
#define MYOpenGLContext NSOpenGLContext
#define MYOpenGLLayer CAOpenGLLayer
#endif
```

Then changed all occurrences of `EAGLContext` and `CAEAGLLayer` to `MYOpenGLContext` and `MYOpenGLLayer` respectively.

This is not enough as functions such as `glOrthof` and `glBindFramebufferOES`, `glGenRenderbuffersOES` are not recognized. What should I use to replace them?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with ios/mac differences here, but it looks like those are specific to iOS opengl. I only have familiarity with [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/), which provides platform-independent opengl calls. Perhaps you could switch your project to use that instead.

Comment: i would also suggest you to use something like GLEW. I prefer to use [GLee](http://elf-stone.com/glee.php) which in my opinion is a bit easier to integrate into a project than GLEW.

Comment: Generally, functions with the suffix -OES are from OpenGL ES 1.1, and you can simply drop the suffix to use them with OpenGL or OpenGL ES 2.0. Similarly, you can use `glOrtho()` instead of `glOrthof()`. Configuring your CAOpenGLLayer will be significantly different from setting up a CAEAGLLayer, though, so that will take a little more effort.

Comment: Thanks @BradLarson! I can start from there. Dirk, IanLink, I would prefer not to modify the original code, as I have very little experience with OpenGL (there was a note in the original question but genpfault took it out).